# Is there any way to set alias for table in DynamicQuery in liferay 7.1

Tags: liferay-7

I want to execute a query on MySQL database which has alias in it in liferay 7.1 so i prefer a way of dynamicquery

my query:

**SELECT id_, groupId, articleId, urlTitle FROM LRCXCHTASK.JournalArticle 
         where version=
          (select max(ja.version) from 
                LRCXCHTASK.JournalArticle ja where ja.articleId = LRCXCHTASK.JournalArticle.articleId );**

for this i have done code :

```
DynamicQuery articleSubDynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class, "articleSub")
            .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("articleSub.articleId").eqProperty("articleParent.articleId"))
            .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.max("articleSub.version"));

    DynamicQuery articleParentDynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class, "articleParent")
            .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("version").eq(articleSubDynamicQuery))
            .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("id"))
            .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("articleId"))
            .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("groupId"))
            .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("urlTitle"));
    List<Object[]> journalArticleIdsList = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(articleParentDynamicQuery);
```

I want list, but it throws  classNotFound JournalArticleImpl exception

If i use

DynamicQuery articleSubDynamicQuery2=JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery();

there is no classloader issues but using this method i can not set alias on table which is mandatory to execute my query

Answer (score 0):

Due to Liferay 7.x OSGI modularization, a **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.journal.model.impl.JournalArticleImpl** is thrown in case you use *DynamicQueryFactoryUtil* because *JournalArticle* class is in public API module, but *JournalArticleImpl* class is in private Impl module, so hibernate code is not able to find that class.

If you use dynamicQuery method provided by Liferay services, you won't have that problem as its implementation is in same classloader than JournalArticleImpl.

Try replacing **DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass({className}.class)** with

```
{className}LocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery()
```

That will avoid classloader issues

In case of JournalArticle, replace DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class, ....) with:
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery()

More info see Liferay forums:

- https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/90985041
- https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/90747545
- https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/90746976
- https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/115276771

Comment: If i use

DynamicQuery articleSubDynamicQuery2=JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery();

there is no classloader issues but using this method i can not set alias on table which is mandatory to execute my query